# I cannot figure out why my output is not displaying correctly from interface

Tags: java

So I am currently learning about interfaces within java and in this program I created 3 separate classes Building.class, Bicycle.class, and Car.class and they are unrelated but they all use the CarbonFootPrint Interface. in my processCarbonFootPrintData class I created an arrayList that holds the data from my objects then I loop through the array list and I get this weird output that does not show the result of my input data.

```
package CarbonFootPrintPackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author cjt1496
 */
public class Building implements CarbonFootPrintInterface {

    private int numberOfFloors;
    private int numberOfJanitors;
    private boolean isBuildingOpenOrClosed;

    double naturalGasConsumed;
    
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public double getNaturalGasConsumed() {
        return naturalGasConsumed;
    }

    public void setNaturalGasConsumed(double naturalGasConsumed) {
        this.naturalGasConsumed = naturalGasConsumed;
    }

    

    public int getNumberOfFloors() {
        return numberOfFloors;
    }

    public void setNumberOfFloors(int numberOfFloors) {
        this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
    }

    public int getNumberOfJanitors() {
        return numberOfJanitors;
    }

    public void setNumberOfJanitors(int numberOfJanitors) {
        this.numberOfJanitors = numberOfJanitors;
    }

    public boolean isIsBuildingOpenOrClosed() {
        return isBuildingOpenOrClosed;
    }

    public void setIsBuildingOpenOrClosed(boolean isBuildingOpenOrClosed) {
        this.isBuildingOpenOrClosed = isBuildingOpenOrClosed;
    }
    
    
    public Building(){
        
    }

    public Building(int numberOfFloors, int numberOfJanitors, boolean isBuildingOpenOrClosed, double naturalGasConsumed) {
        this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
        this.numberOfJanitors = numberOfJanitors;
        this.isBuildingOpenOrClosed = isBuildingOpenOrClosed;
        this.naturalGasConsumed = naturalGasConsumed;
    }
   

    public void calculateCarbonFootPrint(){
        System.out.println("Now Calculating Carbon foot print for a Building ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("How many therms of natural gas has your building consumed?");
        naturalGasConsumed = input.nextDouble();

    }


    @Override
    public void  getCarbonFootPrint() {
       
       System.out.println("The carbon foot print emitted from this building is " + 
               (getNaturalGasConsumed() * 11.7) + "pounds of CO2 from natural gas use.\n");
    }
    
}
```

START OF CAR.CLASS

```
public class Car implements CarbonFootPrintInterface {
   private int numberOfSeats;
   private int steeringWheel;
    
    double emissionConversionFactor;
    double distanceTraveled;
    int numberOfTimesTraveled;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int getNumberOfSeats() {
        return numberOfSeats;
    }

    public void setNumberOfSeats(int numberOfSeats) {
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
    }

    public int getSteeringWheel() {
        return steeringWheel;
    }

    public void setSteeringWheel(int steeringWheel) {
        this.steeringWheel = steeringWheel;
    }
    

    public double getEmissionConversionFactor() {
        return emissionConversionFactor;
    }

    public void setEmissionConversionFactor(double emissionConversionFactor) {
        this.emissionConversionFactor = emissionConversionFactor;
    }

    public double getDistanceTraveled() {
        return distanceTraveled;
    }

    public void setDistanceTraveled(double distanceTraveled) {
        this.distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTimesTraveled() {
        return numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTimesTraveled(int numberOfTimesTraveled) {
        this.numberOfTimesTraveled = numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }

    
    public Car(){
        
    }

    public Car(int numberOfSeats, int steeringWheel, double emissionConversionFactor, double distanceTraveled, int numberOfTimesTraveled) {
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
        this.steeringWheel = steeringWheel;
        this.emissionConversionFactor = emissionConversionFactor;
        this.distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled;
        this.numberOfTimesTraveled = numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }
    
    
      public void calculateCarbonFootPrint(){
        System.out.println("Now Calculating Carbon foot print for a Car ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter your emissionConversionFactor (Must be a decimal)");
        emissionConversionFactor = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your distance traveled in km (Must be a decimal)");
        distanceTraveled = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you traveled to your destination");
        numberOfTimesTraveled = input.nextInt();
    }
   
    
    @Override
    public void getCarbonFootPrint() {
       System.out.println("The carbon foot print emitted from this bicycle is " + 
               getEmissionConversionFactor() * (getDistanceTraveled() * getNumberOfTimesTraveled()) +"Kg CO2e\n");
    }
    
}
```

START OF BICYCLE.CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bicycle implements CarbonFootPrintInterface {
    private int handleBars;
    private boolean KickStand;
    
    double emissionConversionFactor;
    double distanceTraveled;
    int numberOfTimesTraveled;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public int getHandleBars() {
        return handleBars;
    }

    public void setHandleBars(int handleBars) {
        this.handleBars = handleBars;
    }

    public boolean isKickStand() {
        return KickStand;
    }

    public void setKickStand(boolean KickStand) {
        this.KickStand = KickStand;
    }

    public double getEmissionConversionFactor() {
        return emissionConversionFactor;
    }

    public void setEmissionConversionFactor(double emissionConversionFactor) {
        this.emissionConversionFactor = emissionConversionFactor;
    }

    public double getDistanceTraveled() {
        return distanceTraveled;
    }

    public void setDistanceTraveled(double distanceTraveled) {
        this.distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTimesTraveled() {
        return numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTimesTraveled(int numberOfTimesTraveled) {
        this.numberOfTimesTraveled = numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }
    
    
    public Bicycle(){
        
    }

    public Bicycle(int handleBars, boolean KickStand, double emissionConversionFactor, double distanceTraveled, int numberOfTimesTraveled) {
        this.handleBars = handleBars;
        this.KickStand = KickStand;
        this.emissionConversionFactor = emissionConversionFactor;
        this.distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled;
        this.numberOfTimesTraveled = numberOfTimesTraveled;
    }
    
    
    
    
    public void calculateCarbonFootPrint(){
        System.out.println("Now Calculating Carbon foot print for Bicycle ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Enter your emissionConversionFactor (Must be a decimal)");
        emissionConversionFactor = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter your distance traveled in km (Must be a decimal)");
        distanceTraveled = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you traveled to your destination");
        numberOfTimesTraveled = input.nextInt();
    }

    
    
    

    @Override
    public void getCarbonFootPrint() {
       System.out.println("The carbon foot print emitted from this bicycle is " + 
               getEmissionConversionFactor() * (getDistanceTraveled() * getNumberOfTimesTraveled()) +"Kg CO2e\n");
    }
```

START Of PROCESS_CARBON_FOOTPRINT_DATA CLASS

public class ProcessCarbonFootPrintData {

```
public void createCarbonFootPrint(){
    
    Building newBuilding = new Building();
    Car newCar = new Car();
    Bicycle newBicycle = new Bicycle();
    
    newBuilding.calculateCarbonFootPrint();
    newCar.calculateCarbonFootPrint();
    newBicycle.calculateCarbonFootPrint();
    
    ArrayList footPrint = new ArrayList();
    footPrint.add(newBuilding);
    footPrint.add(newCar);
    footPrint.add(newBicycle);
    
    for (Object footPrint1 : footPrint) {
        System.out.println(footPrint1.toString());
    }
    
    
   }
    
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

CarbonFootPrintPackage.Building@42a57993

CarbonFootPrintPackage.Car@75b84c92

CarbonFootPrintPackage.Bicycle@6bc7c054

Comment: "I get weird output", can you be more specific about that part? You are calling the toString method of the Object class, what exactly do you think that will give as a result?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList footPrint = new ArrayList();
footPrint.add(newBuilding);
footPrint.add(newCar);
footPrint.add(newBicycle);

for (Object footPrint1 : footPrint) {
    System.out.println(footPrint1.toString());
}
```

Your arraylist contains Objects, it doesn't know anything further of the type. When you do:

```
for ( Object footPrint1 : footPrint) {

}
```

You also declare the elements to be of type Object.

There are two things you need to do:

1. Be specific about the type. If you want to keep your List as is, with the different types, change your loop to:

   ```
    for ( Object footPrint1 : footPrint) {
      if ( footPrint1 instanceof Car ) 
        System.out.println((Car)footPrint1);
      else if ( footPrint1 instanceof Building ) 
        System.out.println((Building)footPrint1);
      else System.out.println((Bicycle)footPrint1);
    }
   ```

This way, it'll know what type of data to print.

2. By just doing that, you'll still run into the same issue, because you haven't overridden your toString methods.

Add the following to your Car class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "I am a car!!";
}
```

and you'll see that for the Car instance, that line is printed, instead of the memory address.

Override that method for all your classes, and alter the value returned by it the way you want it to be.